# CoreData NSFetchedResultsController of all objects based on a sibling one-to-many relationship property

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, one-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a model with Category, Status and Item entities (and for some reason it's huge):

[image: Model Shot]

I want to maintain a NSFetchedResultsController of all Category objects that have at least one Item with a Status of "open" or "purchased". I've search SO extensively and can find tons of CoreData to-many relationship threads but can't seem to find something like this.

I need a predicate intervention - mine throws an exception currently because I'm trying to use the to-many relationship illegally:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
```

Here's my code as it stands now (bad code, bad!):

```
lazy var searchHeaderController: NSFetchedResultsController<Category> = {

    let request = Category.createFetchRequest()

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "items.status.name == 'open' || items.status.name == 'purchased'")

    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sortOrder", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: mainContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "sortOrder", cacheName: nil)

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Big bummer yo! Error with performFetch in searchHeaderController()  Error:  \(error)")
    }

    return fetchedResultsController

}()
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try using `ANY` or `IN` keyword. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html . As in “status.name == ‘open’ IN items”

Comment: As above your predicate should be an NSCompoundPredicate made of 2 of which they should be format: "ANY items.status.name == open", removing the single quotes around the strings

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I am now using a NSCompoundPredicate and it works for the first fetch but it's not staying up to date with the context.  Can I post the code here or is that technically a new question?  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Using the ANY keyword in your predicate (as mentioned in the comments) will give you a working `FetchRequest` that will get the correct results - initially.

The `FetchedResultsController` however will only be monitoring the `Category` objects and so won't notice any changes in your `Item` objects.

The solution to this is to just maintain an extra field in the `Category` object to help the FRC. If any of the items are open or purchased then set a flag that the FRC **can** monitor for changes.